# Using handlebars.js for dynamic user content?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Handlebars is commonly used on static predefined html templates and then given dynamic data via JSON, but what if the template itself comes from json?

I'm trying to build a community forum whereby I have a template that gets filled in for where the users post goes. The post itself however also contains template information (which is dynamic). How can I get handlebars to process a dynamic template that just came out of ajax?

For example, a users post can contain any or all of the following in any order: text, pictures, links, videos, etc.

The content will look something like this:

> {{text-open}} blablabla heres a picture {{text-close}}{{image-open}}
>   http://someRandomUrl.com {{image-close}} {{image-open}}
>   http://anotherRandomUrl {{image-close}}

I'm not sure how to do this with handlebars. I have the feeling maybe I should just use a string replace function? But would that be the optimal method?

Comment: You mean you're using Handlebars on the server side too?

Comment: No, client side only.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to compile the template:

```
fetch("post.hbs")
    .then(source => Handlebars.compile(source))
    .then(postTemplate => {
        // Do stuff, then fill the template:
        postElement.innerHTML = postTemplate(postData);
    });
```